# Dynamic Type checking based on function argument

Tags: typescript

what am i trying to do is,
i have a function and I'm passing a bunch of boolean flags to it, each of these flags requires different arguments to be passed to same function.

So here is a simple version:

```
enum FLAGS {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b',
  C = 'c'
}

interface ARelatedArgs {
  aBool: boolean
  aString: string
}

interface BRelatedArgs {
  (bEvt: any): void
  bBool: boolean
}

interface CRelatedArgs {
  (cEvt: any): string
  cString: string
}


interface MyFunctionArgs {
  flags: Partial<Record<FLAGS, boolean>>
  // other props based on flag(s) // i can supply one or more flags here!
}

function myFunction(args: MyFunctionArgs) {
  // do something 
}
```

now i want to have type inference based on these call types:

```
// 1st Call to my function
myFunction({
  flags: { [FLAGS.A]: true }
  // all ARelatedArgs
})


// 2nd Call to my function
myFunction({
  flags: { [FLAGS.A]: true, [FLAGS.B]: true }
  // all ARelatedArgs
  // + all BRelatedArgs
})

// last Call to my function
myFunction({
  flags: { [FLAGS.A]: true, [FLAGS.B]: true, [FLAGS.C]: true }
  // all ARelatedArgs
  // + all BRelatedArgs
  // + all CRelatedArgs 
})
```

basically what i want is to check argument types/infer them based on flags that is been passed to it. The interesting thing is that, I dont want to make checks only based on one flag, I could have passed all my 3 flags (A, B, C) and IntelliSense may help me with that? is it possible to have this behavior in typescript?

I know I'm demanding runtime checking from typescript but any idea how can i implement such a thing?

basically i want `MyFunctionArgs` to be something like this:

```
interface MyFunctionArgs {
  flags: Partial<Record<FLAGS, boolean>>
  ...(FLAGS.A in flags && ARelatedArgs),
  ...(FLAGS.B in flags && BRelatedArgs),
  ...(FLAGS.C in flags && CRelatedArgs),
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: should args look like this? `{flags: { [FLAGS.A]: true }, a: {}}`

Comment: yes, you can consider args as the complete arguments list based on flags that is been passed to the function. 
So it can have all Arelated arguments, or A and B related arguments or A, B and C related arguments all at same time if theire respective flags is already passed

Comment: is it okay for you to have them flags and related fields in two separate arguments?

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQJp7N)

Comment: it is already separated, so it should not be a concern i think

Comment: If the previous approach works, then I will write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: that is cool solution, but is there a way to send those arguments all in the same level? not in nested objects ? that would be the ideal solution that i'm looking for

Comment: sure, I separated just because there might be collisions

Comment: check [this one](https://tsplay.dev/NDgMxw)

Comment: great, just one more favour to ask, since this solution is going to be used in react context, I'm looking for passing the relatedArgs next to the flag as props, a use case like this the the best: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/FDD0oAgGwQwZwC4QMIylCCD2EC2BPCAMwFcA7AYwQEsszgCAxcq2sgCmAggG8vvisAOZwAXLwgBtRgBkAggHEAygDo5AXXEIATiQCmAGimzFqgEKbMuw8fnKVySzv0QAvgf7cYZrFihbrDwEIGCUdajIhcQByaKCBACMfP3EiNDhDTwgKMO0IqIhY+PdgAEoAbmAgA

Comment: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/m07MaN)

Comment: Awesome, if you copy/paste it here as an answer, I would accept and upvote! a big thanks to you my friend 

Comment: sure, will do in a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will need a some key-value map that would link the flags enum with the respective types:

```
// type TypeMap = {
//     a: ARelatedArgs;
//     b: BRelatedArgs;
//     c: CRelatedArgs;
// }
type TypeMap = Prettify<
  {
    [K in FLAGS.A]: ARelatedArgs;
  } & { [K in FLAGS.B]: BRelatedArgs } & { [K in FLAGS.C]: CRelatedArgs }
>;
```

[Prettify](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai/blob/main/src/prettify.d.ts?plain=1#L15) is a utility type that makes the end types more readable, by removing `&` and some other things.

Next, we will create a utility that by using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) will map through the passed flags and by using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) it will only keep arguments that we need:

```
type FlagsArgs<T extends MyFunctionArgs['flags']> = {
  [K in keyof T & keyof TypeMap as T[K] extends true ? K : never]: TypeMap[K];
};

// type Result = {
//     a: ARelatedArgs;
//     b: BRelatedArgs;
// }
type Result = FlagsArgs<{ [FLAGS.A]: true; [FLAGS.B]: true }>;
```

To turn into the desired shape we will need the following types:
`ValueOf` - returns all values of an object under every key as a union:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
```

Testing:

```
type FlagsArgs<T extends MyFunctionArgs['flags']> = ValueOf<{
  [K in keyof T & keyof TypeMap as T[K] extends true ? K : never]: TypeMap[K];
}>;

// type Result = ARelatedArgs | BRelatedArgs
type Result = FlagsArgs<{ [FLAGS.A]: true; [FLAGS.B]: true }>;
```

Now, we need to turn the union into an intersection, by using `UnionToIntersection` described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type):

```
type FlagsArgs<T extends MyFunctionArgs['flags']> = UnionToIntersection<
  ValueOf<{
    [K in keyof T & keyof TypeMap as T[K] extends true ? K : never]: TypeMap[K];
  }>
>;

// type Result = ARelatedArgs & BRelatedArgs
type Result = FlagsArgs<{ [FLAGS.A]: true; [FLAGS.B]: true }>;
```

We can also wrap the `FlagsArgs` with `Prettify` to make the result type more literal:

```
type FlagsArgs<T extends MyFunctionArgs['flags']> = Prettify<
  UnionToIntersection<
    ValueOf<{
      [K in keyof T & keyof TypeMap as T[K] extends true
        ? K
        : never]: TypeMap[K];
    }>
  >
>;

// type Result = {
//     aBool: boolean;
//     aString: string;
//     bBool: boolean;
// }
type Result = FlagsArgs<{ [FLAGS.A]: true; [FLAGS.B]: true }>;
```

Looks great!

Usage:

```
function myFunction<T extends MyFunctionArgs>(args: T & FlagsArgs<T['flags']>) {
  // do something
}
```

Final testing:

```
// 1st Call to my function
myFunction({
  flags: { [FLAGS.A]: true },
  aBool: true,
  aString: 'str',
});

// 2nd Call to my function
myFunction({
  flags: { [FLAGS.A]: true, [FLAGS.B]: true },
  aBool: true,
  aString: '',
  bBool: false,
});

// last Call to my function
myFunction({
  flags: { [FLAGS.A]: true, [FLAGS.B]: true, [FLAGS.C]: true },
  aBool: true,
  aString: '',
  bBool: false,
  cString: '',
});
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QPIDMA8AVAfFAXimwG0BrCEAe3WIF0BuAKCdEigFUA7ASyq+xUAkl2AQATgGcIAY2B8umDviIAKDlAgAPMVwAmkqHC4goAfiiqyALk4BKQvgBuVHnqi2uEJxIfbdBpZMUFA2UDxc6BJQQgA0TA4Ezq56weYxaZ7eEsys4NAACuIQwPLoIDgqxJo6EPqGEVHiUABKaRYA3mkhISQA0uFcoZQ0rXS2Lf2M3VAAvplQXj7iuXVIALZQAGIAMgCCAOIAylBdIXuEUADkcFfxIQBCl1cARndpAMLPMu-zTBFicToOAyaB7FoQBBwMR6PbiADmhjORgeVCoCFsLzRCAgxmYITgR2A4gi8NskmJpOYfwBEmBoKgDwhUJhcMRpzSL1R6Mx2NxXGpLFpQJB0A+zOhEFhCKRaRkRJJXDJUApivhgry7Gw+QAsnAwJciiUyhU0sjegMItt9scAHR7cZQcGQyXSxH4uZQABkpyg-UG1sOR1tD0dTJdrJlnp9HT9lqGuyDto+jvFEalbMM81wuWF9OgOpAWyQXDkCkzHJC6ChiNsBTg4nkiEwEJkVHEekwieOsSgWPR-NwObSAHoR1AqMAABbRMDiKhgQwvODSdz8KDVuDw1SSBxj8JQGTGFVIMBgBCmfjQdtQdbt6Cb9kz4oAQiYfzY0C2NckmZwNQCQxC2LUt5H4TMSCuR9JCuOgqiNUoeHKTA0m4BRBBEQFpDLfgUJ6WBEBQDBMHNHp-StChqFobBvWGKjiF1fUjEMUg+joAC6kCYkUBmfCLD6XieiyZZHW1SA9TAKYPRCWZcDSOThyYdASxwoZ1iLFSwMUGj-E4oCNNA8sZVwVQG1raofW-LdfxlHBIOg2DcAcZF9z0KgVSodYSinUl3xYfcAEYKSgD5EAQKBgHc9SN00hQmHUkDVNUZFoNsWMSG7YMHVsbjoFme4UWxHLxBQArCUpJVbCuVVfjsXJ9wAJn0EKwoiqLTGUwz+HigykpSn80r9TL7UdXLewym1g1DYqUDmMruQxCKSogMqFVJKr3hCLkio3RBpHiWY6v88coWC0KEHCyLbw62LuoS26uGStJUt9Cak2ypbSqGyaQ1G5bxuGlMZry+adrGtJyrVDaCu2nldoQfa5TWyrrlq5ggA)

Comment: Hi Again, In case if you are online/avaliable, how we can pluck (for example) ARelatedArgs from `args` and use it within `myFunction()`?

Comment: I tried to get it like `function myFunction<T extends MyFunctionArgs>({ ARGS_FROMMyFunctionArgs, aBool, aString, bBool, cString }: T & FlagsArgs<T['flags']>) {` but there was error below `aBool`, `aString`, `bBool` and `cString`

Comment: basically you could not extract arguments based on flag and use it within function

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood. Do you mean adding extra arguments? Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGX2Xw)?

Comment: how would you turn args object (in function line 56) into something like this `{ aBool, aString, bBool, cString }` and use them within your function, this gives me error in typescript

Comment: now typescript cannot pluck out arguments passed based on flags because it does not know which flag is passed to infer related types (which happens in run time )

Comment: I got what you meant. But it is expected since it is generic and has no fixed flags.

Comment: then let's imagine i want to do something within my function based on an argument that flagA makes me required to pass -> how can i do it in a typescript friendly way and not getting the current errors when extracting those kind of arguments from `args` object?

Comment: @amdev can you include a playground with the desired behavior and suggested changes?